# lights do not eliminate shadow from another light source

Tags: three.js

I was just experimenting with some lightning in three.js and came across a problem which I seem to be the only on having.

The setup is simple, two `PointLight`, one `PlaneGeometry` and one `BoxGeometry`.

```js
"use strict";

var scale = 0.8;
var w = parseInt('' + Math.floor(innerWidth * scale));
var h = parseInt('' + Math.floor(innerHeight * scale));
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, w / h, 0.1, 1000);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
});
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

// init
{
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x404040);

    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.BasicShadowMap;
    renderer.setSize(w, h);

    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}

// plane
{
    let geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(40, 40, 10, 10);
    let material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        color: 0x70B009,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide
    });
    var plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    plane.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3());
    plane.rotateX(90 / 180 * Math.PI);
    plane.receiveShadow = true;
    scene.add(plane);
}

// box
{
    let geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
    let material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
        color: 0xFF6C00
    });

    var orangeCube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    orangeCube.castShadow = true;
    scene.add(orangeCube);
}

// pointlights
{
    var mapSize = 2 << 10;

    var pointLight1 = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, 0.6, 100);
    pointLight1.castShadow = true;
    pointLight1.shadow.mapSize.set(mapSize, mapSize);
    scene.add(pointLight1);

    var pointLight2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, 0.6, 100);
    pointLight2.castShadow = true;
    pointLight2.shadow.mapSize.set(mapSize, mapSize);
    scene.add(pointLight2);
}

// position camera, lights and box
{
    pointLight1.position.set(0, 15, -15);
    pointLight2.position.set(0, 15, 15);

    orangeCube.position.set(0, 5, 0);

    camera.position.set(10, 10, 0);
    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3());
}

// render once
{
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/91/three.min.js"></script>
```

Which works quite well, but one problem. The lights do not eliminate the shadow projected by the other `PointLight`.

Does someone know how to fix this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47224535/overlapping-pointlight-shadows-using-meshlambertmaterial

Comment: @WestLangley well that changed a lot, thank you very much! But should not the shadow completely vanish?

Comment: @WestLangley and could you please be so kind and create an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I will address your additional question in an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47225614/1461008), shadows in `MeshLambertMaterial` are an approximation. Try `MeshPhongMaterial`, for example.

In `MeshPhongMaterial` and `MeshStandardMaterial`, shadows are the absence of light. If there is light from two light sources, shadow intensity can vary where the shadows overlap. See this [three.js example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_lights_spotlights.html).

three.js r.91